# how to extract only letter from a string mixed with numbers with python

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have this table in my dataframe, the `char` column is mixed either with letters only, numbers only or the combination between letters and numbers.

```
char     count
123        24
test       25
te123      26
test123    26
```

I want to extract only the letters, and if the rows has numbers only then I want to make it blank.

The expected results would be:

```
char     count
NaN       24
test      25
te        26
test      26
```

How can I do this in python?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A `re.sub(r"\d+", "", str_to_replace)` would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = {'char': ['123', 'test', 'te123', 'test123'], 'count': [24, 25, 26, 26]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['char'] = df['char'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', x) if bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x)) else np.nan)

print(df)
```

Here `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', x)` removes all non letter chars from the string and the next regex `bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x))` checks if the resulting string contains a letter else makes it NaN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
df["char"] = df["char"].str.extract("([a-zA-Z]+)", expand=False)
```

If you have intermittent characters like `"te12s3t"`, use [`findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) :

```
df["char"] = df["char"].str.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)").str.join("")
```

Or simply [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to handle *both cases* :

```
df["char"] = df["char"].replace("\d+", "", regex=True).mask(lambda s: s.eq(""))
```

Or in a @*Corralien* way, use [`isdigit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) combined with replace :

```
df["char"] = df["char"].mask(df["char"].str.isdigit()).str.replace(r"\d+", "", regex=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   char  count
0   NaN     24
1  test     25
2    te     26
3  test     26
```

Comment: My answer would have been `df['char'].mask(df['char'].str.isdigit()).str.replace(r'\d+', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Hope you're doing good Corralien, I added your suggestion to the answer ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you have already tested this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.replace` as follows:

```py
df["char"] = df["char"].str.replace(r'\d+', '', regex=True)
```